# Need a scripting language for automatic button clicking in software

Tags: windows

So I need to build a bunch of scripts that click certain buttons in a certain Windows program when some stuff happens.

I've been looking around and Autohotkey seems the way to go, but maybe I get some better recommendations.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used SikuliX before and worked well for me. 
You could give it a try.

http://www.sikuli.org/

**EDIT 1:**

There is a hack-y solution that I use for hiding the mouse pointer. You can try it out and see if it serves your purpose

```
Settings.SaveMouseLocation = Location(0,10) # save place on Mac

def hideMouse():
 mmd = Settings.MoveMouseDelay
 Settings.MoveMouseDelay = 0
 Settings.SaveMouseLocationSaved = Env.getMouseLocation()
 mouseMove(Settings.SaveMouseLocation)
 Settings.MoveMouseDelay = mmd

def unhideMouse():
 mmd = Settings.MoveMouseDelay
 Settings.MoveMouseDelay = 0
 mouseMove(Settings.SaveMouseLocationSaved)
 Settings.MoveMouseDelay = mmd
```

usage:

```
hideMouse(); find(something); unhideMouse()
```

Comment: that actually looks a lot better than AHK since it's designed specifically for my purpose

Comment: From what I'm seeing SikuliX moves to mouse to make the clicks which might be a bit annoying to the user. Do you know if there is any way to overcome this?

Comment: Updated the answer as per the new requirement.